# How do I force space between title and author in table of contents (memoir, poemtitle)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am trying to tweak my table of contents so that there is space (filled with ellipses) between the title and the author, followed by a right-justified page number.  When the title is too long, but not long enough to go onto a second line, things are getting messed up.  In my MWE, I provide two entries that don't work followed by one that does, to show the behavior I'm trying to get.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ebook]{memoir}

\newcommand{\cmr}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tocdata}

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage{tgbonum}

\PlainPoemTitle

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\clearpage

\tocdata{toc}{Lydia Wysocki}
\PoemTitle{Communication is an Active Process}

\tocdata{toc}{Matthew Partridge}
\PoemTitle{Performance Excellence Framework}

\tocdata{toc}{Sara L.\ Uckelman}
\PoemTitle[An Orb of Ice-Blue, Held Aloft in a Perfect Hand]{An Orb of Ice-Blue, \\ Held Aloft in a Perfect Hand}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output I get.

[image]

The first two, I would like to have a row of ellipses that extends to the end of the line, and then fills the next line until the author's name, and then the page number properly right-justified.

Comment: I tried your (incomplete) MWE, adding the line `\documentclass{memoir}` at the beginning. The ToC entries all came out as `title lots-of-dots author page-number`. Please provide an MWE that we can process that shows your problem so we don't have to guess at what you might have done. I think your problem might be related to `tocdata` rather than `memoir`.

Comment: Ah!  I see the issue: I hadn't realised that when typesetting code the three backticks had to be on a separate line from the text -- that's why the documentclass wasn't showing up in the formatted version.  Fixed now!

Comment: I ran your revised MWE and got the result you showed. I have tried various experriments and it seems that layout of the author name is very sensitive to the document's textwidth. I have tried fiddling with some of the `texdoc` macros but not come up with anything usable. Hopefully the `texdoc` author will see your question and provide an answer.

Comment: @PeterWilson I think you mean `tocdata` not `texdoc`? (I've removed that tag).